# Safari crash on auto-fill credit card informations

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, safari

On iPhone and iPad i have a wierd problem arround one website and Safari. Website is online shop and when someone order products and fill credit card info, on submit get auto-fill info about storing credit card info. Whether you click Yes or No, safari crash. I reviewed the CSS that `transition` property not made a problem or some jQuery code but I have not found a problem.

Site use Bootstrap v3.3.2, jQuery v1.11.2 and jQuery UI v1.11.4 in side design. Is not my design but I need to fix that mess now.

Comment: I suggest stripping down code until it no longer crashes. Then put the code back in one by one and check if it crashes it. Like that you might find your problem.

Comment: It's impossible to know what's going wrong without more context.  Can you post some code or your work-in-progress implementation?

Comment: What is the version of OSX you are running safari on, as well is safari fully up to date? Can you catch anything in the console before safari crashes ?

Comment: This happens on an iPhone 6 running iOS 8.1. This happens every time on that particular iPhone 6 but iPhone 6 Plus is OK, Also had this problem on the iPhone 4S with iOS 8.1. This is a website: http://www.sportsdepot.com/ It's not my code, I just need to fix problem.

Comment: Try it with a different iPhone 6. And try it with an emulated iPhone 6

Comment: On emulations all is ok. iPod have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is a webkit related bug? I was experiencing something like this a few weeks ago on OS X (Chrome dev build channel). There was an issue opened on this bug on the [Chromium issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=500740).

Comment: Yes.. But this not solve a problem. All brosers work fine. I try with all known and few unknown browsers and all work fine. When I use Safari - BAM! Just switch off.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem too, i was working on something that needed lot of listener.

In one point Firefox crashed but other browser were fine.

Just bind listener on what you need, dont forget to unbind everything else.

But without a link we can just make hypothesis